# AngularDart Component Shadow Dom CSS Encapsulation only working in Dartium

Tags: dart, angular-dart, web-component

I have been playing around with Angular Dart. I like it a lot, but I have come across an issue regarding components and Shadow Dom **CSS encapsulation**.

As far as I know, styles defined inside the component should only apply inside the Shadow Root. Everything works as expected in Chromium, but when I run my application in other browsers (even Chrome) the styles of the component are applied also out of the Shadow Root.

Expected behaviour: **one styled button** and another button with no styles
However, using other browsers running the javascript generated version from Dart Editor I get **two styled buttons** .

This is my main application code

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'mycomponent.dart';
// Temporary, please follow https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/476
@MirrorsUsed(override: '*')
import 'dart:mirrors';

class MyModule extends Module {
  MyModule () {
    type (MyController);
    type (MyComponent);
  }
}

@NgController(
    selector: '[my-controller]',
    publishAs: 'ctrl')
class MyController {
  @NgTwoWay ('something')
  String something;
}

void main() {
  ngBootstrap(modules: [new MyModule ()]);
}
```

My main CSS file is the default CSS generated by Dart Editor. I have only added styles for ng-cloak and the #basic-example id (nothing to do with buttons)

```dart
body {
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin: 15px;
}

h1, p {
  color: #333;
}

#sample_container_id {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#sample_text_id {
  font-size: 24pt;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 140px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}

#basic-example {
  background-color: #dddddd; 
  padding: 20px
}
```

The dart code of the component is also pretty simple:

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@NgComponent (
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: 'mycomponent.html',
    cssUrl: 'mycomponent.css',
    publishAs: 'cmp'
)
class MyComponent {
}
```

This is the html template for the component:

```dart
<div>
  <button>I am a button!</button>
</div>
```

The main HTML of the application just instantiates the component and another button that should not be styled:

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ShadowDomJSBug</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="shadowdomjsbug.css">
  </head>
  <body ng-cloak>
    <div my-controller>

      <!-- [...] -->

      <p>My little component with just one styled button:</p>
      <my-component></my-component>
      <p>The following button should not be styled:</p>
      <button>I should have no styles</button>
    </div>

    <script src="packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/dart" src="shadowdomjsbug.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

As I said before, I expected only one styled button because the styles applied to the component should not apply outside, but in the javascript version generated from Dart Editor I get two styled buttons.

I am using AngularDart 0.9.10 and Dart SDK 1.2.0.

Am I doing something wrong? Maybe I am not understanding the concept of CSS encapsulation. Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does your CSS file look like?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=17676 - This bug basically seems to point to your issue, the CSS being generated also applies to your div -> button sitting outside the component.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Kyle. Indeed, it looks related to that bug. I will follow that issue. Thanks for your quick response.